# elm animation - animating the height of a div so that it fits the content

Tags: animation, elm

I am using [mgold/elm-animation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/elm-animation/latest) to animate the height of a div.
I would like to be able to transition between 0 and a height that fits the content of my div (the equivalent in css of `height: auto;`)

I have found a Jquery solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36995779/4801494) that uses `$(this).css("height","auto").height();` to get the correct height to transition to.

Is there a way to do that in elm?

Comment: I'm not at all sure the jQuery solution will work; animating to arbitrary height appears to be on of the great missing features of the html5 stack

Answer (score 0):

That's seems like a feature request to ask on the lib to me. In https://github.com/mgold/elm-animation/issues

One thing I would do is to try to get that height using auto and they getting the size maybe with display none then using this size as a parameter to elm-animate but you might think of a better way.

Comment: yes it would be ideal if I could get that height value from my elm-app so that I could animate to it but I dont know how to do that.